# Uma coluna em várias linhas

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Já procurei em documentação e não consegui obter o resultado esperado utilizando o bootstrap. A imagem ilustra melhor o que quero fazer

[image: Resultado esperado]

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <div class="content-section-b">
            <h4 class="cat-heading">@Html.ActionLink("Artigos", "Index", "Artigos")</h4>
            <hr class="section-heading-spacer">
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
                <h4 class="section-heading marginTop-0">@artigo.titulo</h4>
                <p class="lead" style="font-size:14px;">@artigo.descricao</p>
                <small><a href="#">Download Artigo</a></small>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <div class="content-section-b">
            <h4 class="cat-heading">@Html.ActionLink("Videos", "Index", "Videos")</h4>
            <hr class="section-heading-spacer">
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <h4 class="section-heading marginTop-0">
                @video.titulo
            </h4>
            <iframe width="300" height="200" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/@video.url" frameborder="0"></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <div class="content-section-b">
            <div class="list-group">
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item active">
                    Agenda
                </a>
                <div style="height:550px;overflow-y:auto">
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item"><small>21/02/2015</small> - Dapibus ac facilisis in Dapibus ac facilisis in Dapibus ac facilisis in </a>
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item"><small>21/02/2015</small> - Morbi leo risus</a>
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item"><small>21/02/2015</small> - Porta ac consectetur ac</a>
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item"><small>21/02/2015</small> - Vestibulum at eros</a>
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item"><small>(21/02/2015)</small> - Dapibus ac facilisis in</a>
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item"><small>(21/02/2015)</small> - Morbi leo risus</a>
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item"><small>(21/02/2015)</small> - Porta ac consectetur ac</a>
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item"><small>(21/02/2015)</small> - Vestibulum at eros</a>
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item"><small>(21/02/2015)</small> - Dapibus ac facilisis in</a>
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item"><small>(21/02/2015)</small> - Morbi leo risus</a>
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item"><small>(21/02/2015)</small> - Porta ac consectetur ac</a>
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item"><small>(21/02/2015)</small> - Vestibulum at eros</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Porém ao tentar adicionar mais coluna ele gera uma nova linha.

Comment: isso resolve seu problema? http://www.bootply.com/90zJfgPBSU#

Comment: Sim. A mágica esta no xs? Não intendo muito isso

Comment: Vou postar como resposta e explicarei como se usar o grid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para conseguir a estrutura em grid utilize este código

***HTML***

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-8">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6"> .col-xs-6 </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6"> .col-xs-6 </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6"> .col-xs-6 </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6"> .col-xs-6 </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6"> .col-xs-6 </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6"> .col-xs-6 </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-4"></div>
</div>
```

Você pode ver o resultado nesta **[DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/90zJfgPBSU#)**

Cada coluna do grid possui tamanhos que irão de 1 a 12, isso você já deve ter entendido, ele possui 4 tipos de colunas com comportamento diferentes em cada resolução.

- `col-xs-xx` (Mantém o grid para telas abaixo de < *768px*)
- `col-sm-xx` (Mantém o grid para telas acima ou igual a ≥ *768px*)
- `col-md-xx` (Mantém o grid para telas acima ou igual a ≥ *992px*)
- `col-lg-xx` (Mantém o grid para telas acima ou igual a ≥ *1200px*)

Ou seja, dependendo da situação você deve prestar atenção em qual das classes utilizar, pois o tamanho da tela pode interferir no grid.

Você pode ler mais em [Grid Boostrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)

Answer (score 2):

Você tem que criar uma div com largura 8 na esquerda, e uma com largura 4 na direita. Aí dentro da div com largura 8 você vai criar 2 colunas com largura 6 e 3 linhas.

Answer (score 2):

São duas colunas sendo, respectivamente, de 8 e 4 espaços, totalizando 12 – o máximo natural pelo Bootstrap 3.

Dentro da primeira coluna de 8 espaços, teremos outras duas com 6, totalizando também 12.

> *Mas, como é possível uma coluna de 6 já dentro de uma coluna de valor inferior?*

**R:** A quebra de colunas é baseado no tamanho do seu pai, o que faz a porcentagem vir à tona. No caso, seriam 2x de 6 colunas, resultando em 12 que é a largura máxima, em camadas, permitida pela entidade pai/superior.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-lg-8">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="mini-block">
          rock your body
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="mini-block">
          rock your body
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="mini-block">
          rock your body
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="mini-block">
          rock your body
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4">
    <div class="big-block">
        do you like to rock your body?
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.col-lg-6 {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }

.mini-block {
    background-color: purple;
    color: #fff; 
  }

.big-block {
    background-color: yellow;
    position: relative;
  }
```

[Demonstração](http://www.bootply.com/UlXCF6p9Zw)